# Authentication error in moodle when entering administration logins

Tags: moodle

Every time I enter my administration username and password, I get this error message:

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home/gosmartm/public_html/moodle/mod/quiz/lang/en/quiz.php on line 870

The file and line are different every time; I've updated the execution time to 120s but still get the same problem.

Can someone help me?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Can you switch debugging on and report the result - edit /config.php and add these 2 lines after $CFG = new stdClass();

```
$CFG->debug = 32767;
$CFG->debugdisplay = true;
```

If you can report the full php trace, not just the last line - it's unlikely a language file is causing the time out, its probably something happening before that.